# MVC Actionlink & Bootstrap Modal Submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm developing an MVC 5 web application. Within one of my Razor Views I have a table which spits outs several rows of data. Beside each row of data is a Delete button. When the user clicks the delete button I want to have the Bootstrap Modal popup and ask the user to confirm their deletion.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Data) {
<tr>
 <td>...</td>
 <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-xs", data_toggle = "modal", data_target = "#myModal" })</td>
</tr>
}
```

As it is, when the user clicks the Delete button the Modal pops up fine, but I can't seem to get the ID in the Actionlink parameter to pass to the Confirm button within my Modal so that it will then be sent to the delete action in my controller.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
             <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete Nomination</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
           Are you sure you wish to delete this nomination?
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
           <button type="button" id="mySubmit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: Assign a click event to you modal sumbit button that creates a ajax call back to your controller and just store your ID in a hidden field. I can give you an example if you need one

Comment: Shouldn't it be new { id = itemin.ID } instead of item.ID? Because you declared the variable name to itemin

Comment: @heymega Thanks for your reply. An example or snippet of code would be great. I'm not sure how to get the ActionLink parameter ID into a hidden field?

Comment: @heymega pls example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //Everytime we press delete in the table row
    $('.delete').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //Update the item to delete id so our model knows which one to delete
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $('#item-to-delete').val(id);

    });


    //Everytime we press sumbit on the modal form...
    $('#mySubmit').click(function() {

        //Get the id to delete from the hidden field
        var id = $('#item-to-delete').val();


        //Call our delete actionresult and pass over this id
        $.post(@Url.Action("Delete", "Delete"), { id : id } , function (data) {

            alert("Deleted");

        });


    });

</script>
```

and your html...

```
@Html.Hidden("item-to-delete", "", new { @id = "item-to-delete"})
@foreach (var item in Model.Data) {
<tr>
    <td>...</td>

    <td><a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" data-toggle= "modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="@item.id">Delete</a></td>

</tr>
}
```

Your controller action I assume is something like this...

```
public ActionResult Delete(Guid id)
{


}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Even if your code isn't 100% correct i'll still be able to get it working from here. Thanks again.

Comment: can`t get id from #item-to-delete

Comment: in the bootstrap documentation it says we can either choose to use javascript or data attributes to archive the same. So how can we do this with using data attributes, without javascript?

Comment: @tgriffiths can you please tell me how you made it work?

Comment: How can I add html.AntiforgeryToken to anchor links or somewhere in JS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a null after the second Delete then it should work but you will still have an issue with this because what it's going to try and do is open the page inside your modal the best way to achieve what you want to do is to do an ajax call to the server and in the success bring back the data into that div that is around your modal

Comment: This is not an answer its a comment. *Comments posted as an answer are subject to removal.*  For more info check this [**Link**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174/339153)